# node failed exit code 1

Tags: node.js, npm, photoshop, child-process, photoshop-script

I am trying to run photoshop script through childprocess execsync using the following code, But am getting a error

```
try {
    const child_process = require("child_process")
    child_process.execSync('"C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe" Z:/myfile.jsx', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("error here");
        }
    })
        .on('close', function (code, signal) {console.log('go to next step')})
} catch (err) {
    err.stdout;
    err.stderr;
    err.pid;
    err.signal;
    err.status;
}
```

But I am getting a error

```
{ Error: Command failed: "C:/Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Photoshop CC 2019/Photoshop.exe" Z:/Render2.0/psTextConvertor.jsx
    at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:611:11)
    at Object.execSync (child_process.js:648:13)
    at startPhotoshop (Z:\Render2.0\tempsqs.js:422:23)
    at mergeFontData (Z:\Render2.0\tempsqs.js:410:9)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (Z:\Render2.0\tempsqs.js:282:21)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
  status: 1,
  signal: null,
  output: [ null, <Buffer >, <Buffer > ],
  pid: 5492,
  stdout: <Buffer >,
  stderr: <Buffer > }
```

but the script runs perfectly , but I am not getting exit code , please help

Comment: I tried with exec instead of execSync , still getting same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems getting Photoshop to launch and run a script from node as a child process.  I was working on a Windows system with Adobe CS6 at the time and was able to get this working by writing a powershell script to launch photoshop with args to execute an ExtendScript file, and *then* used `child-process.exec` to run that powershell script from node.

powershell:

```
Start-Process -FilePath  "C:\Program Files\Adobe\Adobe Photoshop CS6 (64 Bit)\Photoshop.exe" -ArgumentList "C:\Scripts\MyScript.jsx" -Wait
```

node:

```js
function runPowershell(path) {

  var spawn = require("child_process").exec, child;
  
  child = spawn(`powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File ${path} -NoExit`);
  child.stdout.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Powershell Data: " + data);
  });
  child.stderr.on("data", function (data) {
    console.log("Powershell Errors: " + data);
  });
  child.on("exit", function () {
    console.log("Powershell Script finished");
  });
  child.stdin.end(); //end input
}

runPowershell("path/to/powershellScript.ps1");
```